# How to get partial match with soup.find()?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

For some reason I wasn't able to find the answer to this somewhere.
So, I'm using this

```
soup.find(text="Dimensions").find_next().text
```

to grab the text after "Dimensions". My problem is on the website I'm scraping sometimes it is displayed as "Dimensions:" (with colon) or sometimes it has space "Dimensions " and my code throws an error. So that's why I'm looking for smth like (obviously, this is an invalid piece of code) to get a partial match:

```
soup.find(if "Dimensions" in text).find_next().text
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've just found out looks like it's much simpler than I thought

```
soup.find(text=re.compile(r"Dimensions")).find_next().text
```

does what I need